# Curly curly operator inside survey function

Tags: r, survey, rlang, tidyeval

I have a survey data with weight column like this dummy sample:

```
df <- structure(
  list(
    device = c(
      "Digital",
      "No Device",
      "No Device",
      "Digital",
      "Digital",
      "No Device",
      "Digital",
      "Digital",
      "Analouge",
      "Digital"
    ),
    sex = structure(c(1, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 1), format.spss = "F8.2"),
    region = structure(c(15, 3, 18, 18, 30, 18, 54, 50, 30,
                         38), format.spss = "F8.0"),
    age_group = structure(c(3, 3,
                            5, 7, 6, 4, 7, 7, 6, 7), format.spss = "F8.2"),
    weight = structure(
      c(
        845.674012066483,
        523.065753702848,
        551.805833394951,
        454.282517089281,
        1234.09384828581,
        1046.04985735983,
        994.717870661103,
        1013.62211131793,
        1307.98181670913,
        544.360713556522
      ),
      format.spss = "F8.2"
    )
  ),
  row.names = c(NA,
                -10L),
  class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame")
)
```

I am using srvyr package to make a survey object and do my analysis:

```
library(srvyr)
sv_sample <- df %>%
  srvyr::as_survey_design(weights = weight)
```

Here I am doing a cross tab interaction between device and sex for example and it is ok

```
sv_sample %>% 
  mutate(sex = as.factor(sex) )%>%
  mutate_at(vars(device),
            fct_explicit_na,
            na_level = "to_impute") %>%
  group_by(sex ,device) %>%
  summarize(
    proportion = srvyr::survey_mean(na.rm = TRUE),
    total = srvyr::survey_total(na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  select(-proportion_se, -total_se) %>%
  ungroup()
```

output:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 4
  sex   device    proportion total
  <fct> <fct>          <dbl> <dbl>
1 1     Digital        0.796 4073.
2 1     No Device      0.204 1046.
3 2     Analouge       0.385 1308.
4 2     Digital        0.298 1014.
5 2     No Device      0.316 1075.
```

I need to create similar cross tab for device vs other demo variables in my data like age , region , family_size etc etc so instead of copy & paste the cross tab snippet several times I tried to make a function with Curly curly operator. What am I missing here?

```
    crosstab <- function(survey_data, vars1 , vars2) {
      mutate(demo = as.factor{{ vars1 }} )%>%
        mutate_at(vars{{ vars2 }},
                  fct_explicit_na,
                  na_level = "to_impute") %>%
        group_by(demo ,{{ vars2 }}) %>%
        summarize(
          proportion = srvyr::survey_mean(na.rm = TRUE),
          total = srvyr::survey_total(na.rm = TRUE) ) %>%
        select(-proportion_se, -total_se) %>%
        ungroup()
}

 crosstab(sv_sample, sex ,device)
```

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. `vars{{ vars2 }}` is invalid syntax. `vars` is a function: `vars({{vars2}})`. Same for `as.factor`.
2. `{{…}}` interpolates a *single* value. If you want to pass multiple values, you either need to use `!!!` in combination with `enquos` or you can just pass the variables in dots (i.e. `...`), no need for metaprogramming.

   However, in your case it seems as if you’re actually only passing a single variable name, so instead it would probably appropriate to rename `vars1` and `vars2` to `var1` and `var1` — or, better yet, give them *proper* names: `var1` is an un-descriptive, cryptic variable name.

Instead of `mutate_at(vars(...), f)`, also consider using its modern replacement, [`mutate(across(..., f))`](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html); this further simplifies your code. See [*Taking multiple columns without `...`*](https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-multiple-columns.html).

Comment: I didnot fully get your second point . did you mean rename or still I need to use `{{…}}`                                              
`function(survey_data, demo1 , demo2) {
  mutate(demo = as.factor vars({{demo1}}) )%>%
    mutate_at(vars({{demo2}}),
              fct_explicit_na,
              na_level = "to_impute") %>%
    group_by(demo1 ,{{demo2}}) %>%
    summarize(
      proportion = srvyr::survey_mean(na.rm = TRUE),
      total = srvyr::survey_total(na.rm = TRUE) ) %>%
    select(-proportion_se, -total_se) %>%
    ungroup()`

Comment: @DanG Well, using `demo1` instead of `vars1` hasn’t improved the variable name. Either way, the second point only applies if you try to pass multiple names to `vars1` or `vars2`, in which case your code won’t work. If you pass single names only, that code is fine (but you should still find more descriptive variable names).

Comment: Hi Konrad. `enexprs()` is a function for experts only. We've updated the rlang doc to make this clearer. Could you please mention `enquos()` in this post? Thanks :) Even better, the standard way of going from one `{{` var to multiple is to pass a selection to `across()`, this way no metaprogramming is needed.

Comment: @LionelHenry Great work on the new ‘rlang’ documentation, looking very nice!